# Converting seconds to hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: java, android, string, time, timer

I want to use count up timer in android for long hours...

Currently, I am using this code, but after some hours, say after 10 hours, the format goes like 10 : 650 :56 (hh:mm:ss)... for lesser time, it works perfectly...

```
 private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

        int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        int hours = minutes / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);

        String timer = ("" + String.format("%02d", hours) + " :  "
                + String.format("%02d", minutes) + " : "
                + String.format("%02d", seconds));

        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);

        sendLocalBroadcast(timer);

    }

};
```

Comment: you got some advance?

Answer (score 2):

Your code for minutes is almost right, but you have to modulus it by 60 just like you do for seconds.  Otherwise your value is going to still include all the hours.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
private static String timeConversion(int totalSeconds) {

    final int MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR = 60;
    final int SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE = 60;

    int seconds = totalSeconds % SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE;
    int totalMinutes = totalSeconds / SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE;
    int minutes = totalMinutes % MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR;
    int hours = totalMinutes / MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR;

    return hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds;
}
```

You can found other solution in:

> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/62713/69166